# Avoid I2C Clock stretching

Tags: i2c, texas-instruments

I'm trying to read the temperature of a Si7050 using a TI CC3220SF. I'm not sure if clock stretching is handled correctly from the TI's driver as well as the NACK option (alternative to clock streching, according to the datasheet).

Is there a way to read that temperature avoiding those specific features? I mean, for me it's ok to send the "measure" command and come back to reading out the converted value after a conversion-time.

I don't understand if it's possible and (if it is) how.

Comment: The chip has both alternatives. You want "No hold master mode", 0xf3. Please check the datasheet, p12.

Comment: As said, I know this alternative, but it requires to handle the NACK until the slave answers. I'm quite new to the TI's drivers lib and I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the clock stretching to work. I've ended up in this way:

```
_i16 WriteRegister(_u8 address)
{
    I2C_Transaction i2cTransaction;
    _u8 writeBuf[1];

    writeBuf[0] = address;

    i2cTransaction.slaveAddress = SI7051_ADDRESS;
    i2cTransaction.writeBuf = writeBuf;
    i2cTransaction.writeCount = 1;
    i2cTransaction.readBuf = NULL;
    i2cTransaction.readCount = 0;

    return I2C_transfer(_i2cHandle, &i2cTransaction);
}

_i16 ReadRegister(_u8 *readBuf, _u8 readCount)
{
    I2C_Transaction i2cTransaction;

    i2cTransaction.slaveAddress = SI7051_ADDRESS;
    i2cTransaction.writeBuf = NULL;
    i2cTransaction.writeCount = 0;
    i2cTransaction.readBuf = readBuf;
    i2cTransaction.readCount = readCount;

    return I2C_transfer(_i2cHandle, &i2cTransaction);
}

void Measure()
{
    _u8 readBuf[2] = {0, 0};

    WriteRegister(SI7051_MEASURE_NO_HOLD);
    while (ReadRegister(readBuf, 2) == 0) Task_sleep(1);
    // convert measurement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The driver does not handle clock stretching because it is already handled by the hardware.

Ensure that the I²C Master Clock Low Timeout Count is set high enough (see section 7.2.1.6 of the Technical Reference Manual).

Comment: Thank for the clarification. Would you mind to link the document you're talking about? I'm not sure to read the correct manual.

Comment: Ok, found: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru367c/swru367c.pdf, I didn't find before because I was looking for CC3220*!

Comment: I found the relevant register at section 7.3.1.10: I2CMCLKOCNT. It's the first time I use such an MCU and It's not clear to me how to set the register.

Comment: Well, I think the way is to use the macro `HWREG`. I.e. : `HWREG(I2CA0_BASE + I2C_O_MCLKOCNT) = 0x10;` but even with the longest timeout it doesn't work and the `I2C_transfer` fails.

Comment: Is the actual delay longer than the highest possible timeout?

Comment: If I'm not wrong: the conversion time is (max) 10.8 ms. Setting the `I2CMCLKOCNT` register to 0xFF leads to 4080 counts. At 100 kHz it means a timeout of more than 40 ms.